# How can I plot a graph of a unit circle in R Programming?

Tags: r

R code to plot graph of 1⁄4 circle in the 1st quadrant. Points in circle are red and others are
blue.
[The output image should be like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTcQq.png)

Comment: Please show us what you already tried first.

Comment: Hello Prabesh, I agree it would be to good if I rephrase your question stating what you're trying to do and what you're struggling with as this at the moment read like a demand that some random person from the internet should do the work for you.

Comment: It is customary to accept answers if they're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot() + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 1), fill = 'red', colour = 'red') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 0.35, yend = 0.8)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0.8, xend = 0.35, yend = 0.8)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.35, y = 0, xend = 0.35, yend = 0.8)) +
  annotate('text', x = -0.04,y = -0.04, label = '0') +
  annotate('text', x = -0.04,y = 0.94, label = '1') +
  annotate('text', x = 0.94,y = -0.04, label = '1') +
  annotate('text', x = 0.35/2,y = 0.84, label = 'x') +
  annotate('text', x = 0.4,y = 0.4, label = 'y') +
  annotate('text', x = 0.15,y = 0.44, label = 'r') +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "blue",
                                    colour = "lightblue"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor =element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]